# How to preserved an element input when print using this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that want to be printed. I use this script to do the job

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gAutoPrint = true;

function printDiv(){


    if (document.getElementById != null){
    var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
    if (document.getElementsByTagName != null){
    var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (headTags.length > 0) html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
    }

    html += '\n</HE' + 'AD>\n<BODY>\n';
    var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("div_content");

    if (printReadyElem != null) html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
    else{
    alert("Error, no contents.");
    return;
    }

    html += '\n</BO' + 'DY>\n</HT' + 'ML>';

    var printWin = window.open("","processPrint");
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();

    if (gAutoPrint) printWin.print();
    } else alert("Browser not supported.");

}
```

It open a new window and recreate the form to be printed. But, the input element value is not preserved.

How do I preserved the input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
var printWin = window.open("","processPrint");
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
```

With:

```
var printWin = window.open("","processPrint").document.write(html)
```